# StartActivityForResult result in a new item on OverviewScreen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to launch an activity from another application inside my own app.  I have control over both applications.

For it, I'm using the explicit intent and it works well.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("br.com.example.app","br.com.exemple.app.myactivity");
intent.setComponent(componentName);
```

My problem occurs when I click on the overview button, the new application appears inside the same item when overview screen (Recents Screen). Thus, the user can figure out if he is one the App1 or App2. Actually, he will think that he is still inside App1.

How do I force it to appear on a different item on the Overview Screen?

I already tried to use

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
```

and

```
    <activity
        android:name=".myactivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/ApiBaseThemeNoActionBar"
        android:documentLaunchMode="always">
    </activity>
```

It seems to work well when using only startActivity(intent).

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK):

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched.

So in your case, I guess if you're asking for a result, android forces you to stay in the same task.